# How to assign a group to user based on their email id on registration

Tags: magento-1, customer-group, register

I am making a project In which I have to differentiate between the user who have registered I want that if some one registered with the id

> abc@gmail.com

He should be automatically assign to student group

and if user registered with the id other then this

> gmail.com

then He should be assign to a group say Guest

So can any one tell me. where I have to start for this as I search alot but can not get answer related to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this by magento `event Observer` and find a trigger an `observer` on `customer save events` and change customer group accordingly.

### You can try with this two Event

1. `customer_save_before`
2. `customer_save_after`

First of all ,i `guess` that you have `already create customer groups` Student,Guest from **Admin>Customers>Customer group**.

**Find details on event and observer** [`here`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

### Model Approach

**Step1:** trigger an event on basic of `customer_save_before`

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <change_customer_group>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>magento63798/observer</class>
                    <method>ChangeCustomerGroup</method>
                </change_customer_group>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

**Step2:** Magento `Observer Code is below` and guess that `guest custome group id is 2,Student is 5`.

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento63798_Model_Observer
{
    public function ChangeCustomerGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

        $customer=$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        Mage::log('My log entry'.$customer->getId(), null, 'Magento63798.log');

        $StudentGroup=5;
        $GuestGroupId=2;
        list($user, $domain) = explode('@',$customer->getEmail());

        if ($domain == 'gmail.com'):
            /* set Customer group as Stiudent */
            $customer->setData('group_id',$StudentGroup);   
        // use gmail
        else:
            $customer->setData('group_id',$GuestGroupId);   
        endif;


    }
```

See another example [How to automatically send a transactional email on customer group change?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45308/how-to-automatically-send-a-transactional-email-on-customer-group-change/45310#45310)

Comment: I'm looking to implement something exactly like this... i posted a thread about it today. Does this code still work in magento EE? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190491/give-a-percentage-off-to-everyone-that-has-a-specific-email-address-ie-employe

Comment: Yes,it will  works!!